# Responsive list item

Tags: html, css, responsive

In responsive mode I need to place some one lined li to multi line li. lis are not same in width. It is not possible to use % . lis will start from begging of every row.

How can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: Most likely it's because they are `display: inline`. Set `li { display: inline-block }`, but please show your code, it's impossible to know for sure if you just add a screenshot and no HTML and CSS

Comment: @abu abu, can you please add your code instead of just image?

Comment: @abu abu Hope this will help you https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_contact_chips.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend CSS Flexbox for this:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap
}
```

You will see as the screen size drops, the li elements will wrap on to the next line.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rmfx4qdw/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that, [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2786sxL/)

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example i made for both fluid and fixed responsive lists (*play* with the window width to see the difference between them) https://jsfiddle.net/ahentea/0542ynvh/

For a fluid list:

```
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

In the above example each `li` has a with of 25% out of 100% therefore you can have 4 `li` on a row, but using nth-child you can make any of the `li` have a explicit width just make sure it will equal `100%` everything over that will fall underneath.

For a list with fixed width elements:

```
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li:nth-child(1) {
  width: 300px;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 225px;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) {
  width: 130px;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) {
  width: 80px;
}
```

In this case when the width of the container can not accommodate the width of each `li` then they will fall underneath from the last to the first.

**Pro tip**, if you decide to implement this method make sure that none of the li exceed the minimum window otherwise they will overflow. For example if one of your `li` has a width of `450 px` then for all window widths lower than `450 px` that `li` will `overflow`

**Pro tip 2** When using `display: inline-block` it will add by default whitespace between elements you can get rid of that space by adding to the parent element `font-size: 0`